# Cannot SSH Dataproc Master in Cluster

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, gcloud, google-cloud-dataproc

I've been trying to create a cluster in Dataproc using as initialization script the [jupyter repository](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/tree/master/jupyter).

But when I try to ssh to the master so to be able to access the Jupyter interface running this command:

```
gcloud compute ssh --zone=zone_name \
                   --ssh-flag="-D 10000" \
                   --ssh-flag="-N" \
                   --ssh-flag="-n" "cluster1-m" &
```

I get the error:

> Permission denied (publickey). ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh)
>   [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].

I could confirm that all ssh keys are created normally. I tried this other option then:

```
gcloud compute ssh --zone=zone_name \
                   --ssh-flag="-D 10000" \
                   --ssh-flag="-N" \
                   --ssh-flag="-n" "will@cluster1-m" &
```

Which seems to work as I can ssh into the instance but now I get the error:

> bind: Cannot assign requested address
>   channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 10000 Could
>   not request local forwarding.

For creating the cluster I used:

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create $CLUSTER_NAME \
--metadata "JUPYTER_PORT=8124,JUPYTER_CONDA_PACKAGES=numpy:pandas:scikit-learn:jinja2:mock:pytest:pytest-cov" \
--initialization-actions \
    gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/jupyter/jupyter.sh \
--bucket $BUCKET_NAME
```

and I'm running this in a docker image Debian 8.9 (jessie).

If you need any extra information please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If you verified you can do a normal SSH into the cluster, then if you're just getting the `bind: Cannot assign requested address` error it probably means you have another SSH session with local port forwarding already on your current machine using port `10000` already. If you see the `bind` error, you should always first try a different local port, like `-D 12345`. You can use `top` or your task manager to check if you have a hanging `ssh -D` command somewhere still running and occupying port 10000.

Comment: Hi Dennis, thanks for the help. I also tried different ports and checked for some other process that might be still running in background but there was none. What I tested after posting the question was installing everything outside docker, in my own machine, and then everything worked fine. I still don't quite understand what happens in the Docker image that breaks the ssh (as I could successfully ssh using `will@hostname` I wonder if user root has something to do with it but I'm not sure, just guessing)

Comment: Ah that makes sense; you may just need some port mapping flags for your Docker container: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32070789/portforwarding-from-within-docker-container and https://bobcares.com/blog/docker-port-expose/